# Stuck on executing this function after 10 seconds of page load.

Tags: javascript, modalpopupextender, simplemodal

I created this function that checks for user's cookies and then shows a newsletter Popup. I need to load this after the user has spent 10 seconds navigating on the site. I've use window.setTimeout but it hasn't worked so far. The script works beautifully except for this 10 second delay execution. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
theme.ModalNewsletter = function() {
  if ($.cookie('tada-cookies')) {
  } 
  else {
    var el = $('#newslettermodal');
    if (el.length) {
      $('#newslettermodal').removeClass("hide");
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: el
        },
        type: 'inline'
      });
    }

  }
  $.cookie('tada-cookies', 'true', { expires: 7});
}
```

Comment: Show how you were calling `setTimeout` so we can help you.

Comment: Ya, where's the setTimeout? lol

Comment: Where's the `setTimeout(theme.ModalNewsletter, 10000);`?

Comment: theme.ModalNewsletter = function() {
  if ($.cookie('tada-cookies')) {
  } 
  else {
    var el = $('#newslettermodal');
    if (el.length) {
      $('#newslettermodal').removeClass("hide");
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: el
        },
        type: 'inline'
      });
    }
    setTimeout(theme.ModalNewsletter, 10000);
  }
  $.cookie('tada-cookies', 'true', { expires: 7});
}

Comment: Apologies I thought I included it.

Comment: The `setTimeout` is **inside** the function it is supposed to call... You should put `setTimeout` **outside** `ModalNewsletter`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your timeout passes the function itself and doesn't execute it.

Correct way:

`setTimeout(theme.ModalNewsletter, 10000);`

Incorrect way:

`setTimeout(theme.ModalNewsletter(), 10000);`

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated. `setTimeout(theme.ModalNewsletter, 10000); {
theme.ModalNewsletter = function() 

  if ($.cookie('tada-cookies')) {
  } 
  else {
    var el = $('#newslettermodal');
    if (el.length) {
      $('#newslettermodal').removeClass("hide");
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: el
        },
        type: 'inline'
      });
    }

  }
  $.cookie('tada-cookies', 'true', { expires: 7});
}`

Answer (score 0):

Is this the right approach?

```js
setTimeout(theme.ModalNewsletter, 10000); {
theme.ModalNewsletter = function() 

  if ($.cookie('tada-cookies')) {
  } 
  else {
    var el = $('#newslettermodal');
    if (el.length) {
      $('#newslettermodal').removeClass("hide");
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: el
        },
        type: 'inline'
      });
    }

  }
  $.cookie('tada-cookies', 'true', { expires: 7});
}
```